# Create Rectangle from Left,Right,Top and Bottom

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I have a list that contains left,right,bottom and top of rectangles.

[image]

How can i cast this to a  `Rectangle[]` array?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Rectangle__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: @dr.null can you add this as an answer please..

Answer (score 3):

**Define Rectangle**

```
Rectangle(left,top,width,height)
Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[2]
{
    new Rectangle(0,0,100,50),
    new Rectangle(200,100,200,50),
};



List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.X = 5;
rect.Y = 10;
rect.Width = 100;
rect.Height = 50;
rectangles.Add(rect);
```

**Obtain height and width with bottom and right**

```
int left = 100;
int top = 50;
int right = 400;
int bottom = 250;

int width = right - left;
int heigth = bottom - top;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(left, top, width, heigth);
```

**Draw Rectangle Array**

```
private void DrawRectangle()
{
    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[]
    {
       new Rectangle(0,0,100,50),
       new Rectangle(200,100,200,50),
       new Rectangle(300,200,160,60)
    };
    foreach(var rect in rectangles)
    {
       System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
       System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
       formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
       formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, rect);
       myBrush.Dispose();
       formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this can be achieved using a single line of code as mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`Rectangle.FromLTRB(left, right, top, bottom);`